# switch asp.net core run os from windows to linux

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have built an ASP.NET Core web app using Visual Studio community (NOTE: on my local Windows machine) that I am satisfied with. I now want to deploy it to the web. Only, my deploy environment is a Linux machine, not a windows machine. In the `\bin\Debug\net5.0` and `\bin\Release\net5.0` there are several `.exe` and `.dll` files that Linux can not run. How do I switch the run environment from windows to linux? Am I missing something here?

Comment: you should check the TargetFramework in .csproj file.
It should be something like `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>`
And You should make sure that you are not using .net framework libraries but .netcore libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, if you want to run the asp.net core application on the linux. You should firstly make sure you have set the publish environment to the protable or linux.

Then you should make sure you have installed the [.net core runtime](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/5.0) for linux on that linux machine.  Then you could use apache or nginx as the reverse proxy server to rub the application.

More details about how to host asp.net core application on Nginx, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

More details about how to host asp.net core application on apache , you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-apache?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

More details about how to set the target environment , you could refer to below image:

[image]